# IO::All: how do I read from ARGV and DATA?

Tags: perl

How do I create an [IO::All](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO%3A%3AAll) object to read the file handles ARGV and DATA?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010_000;
use IO::All;

# none of these work...
my $io = io->handle(DATA);
my $io = io->handle(\*DATA);
my $f = \*DATA;
my $io = io->handle($f);
my $io = io->handle({$f});
my $io = io->handle({DATA});
my $io = io->handle({\*DATA});

say $io->slurp();

__DATA__
FOO
BAR
QUUX
```

Comment: I spent an hour or so poking around the URL and Perl manual, but I'm unable to find anything that will help.

Comment: [File a bug.](http://rt.cpan.org)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a bug.  Passing in a handle doesn't appear to work, even though the docs say it should.  Here's an example which eliminates the possible complexities of `DATA`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use IO::All;

open my $fh, "<", "/etc/passwd" or die $!;

# Either of these should work according to the docs.
# my $io = IO::All->new($fh);
my $io = io->file->handle($fh);
print $io->all;
```

[Please file a bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=IO-All).